# Pyspark: How to fill the missing values from another row

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

How can we replace null value in pyspark after grouping by id?
For each id, I need to replace the null value with the value at -20 week

```
ID  |week | Value
A   | -21 | null
B   | -22 | null
B   | -20 | 0.4521
A   | -22 | null
A   | -20 | 0.85678
B   | -21 | null
C   | -20 | 0.4563
B   | -19 | 0.4678
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet on this would be take out the values at week -20 and join with the original dataframe, then use the when function in pyspark. Let's day df is your dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df2 = df.filter(df.week==-20).select('ID','Value').withColumnRenamed('Value','Value2')
df3 = df.join(df2,on=['ID'],how='left_outer')
df4 = df3.withColumn('new_value',when(df3.Value.isNull(),df3.Value2).otherwise(df3.Value))
df5 = df4.select('ID','new_value').withColumnRenamed('new_value','value')
```

df5 is your required dataframe